# Safe DateTime in a T-SQL INSERT statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Been running in problem lately with using a DateTime in a T-SQL INSERT INTO statement. Work fine on one machine but might not work on another and I guess this has to do with locale settings.

So if I have DateTime variable what is the safe way of using that in a SqlStatement string that it will always work regardless on local system settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [parameterized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) `INSERT` query.

Most likely, your code is assembling the SQL command string. That also makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Deleted comment, thought they were doing it in TSQL. Just noticed asp.net tag.

Comment: Another issue is that the SQL DateTime range is _smaller_ than the .NET DateTime range.

Comment: @MartinSmith The first thing I saw were the C# and ASP.NET tags. Then I saw your comment and I thought "Did I screw up?" :)

Comment: @Oded Thanks for the heads up. But you have to agree that most likely using parameters will solve OP's problem. But I'm now curious, how do you handle that limitation?

Comment: @Adrian - True, probably not the issue for the OP, but still a possible issue (say the system clock was reset). How to handle? You must sanitize the dates - not allow certain dates go through.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, Don't think the range will ever be a problem for me but if it would, maybe better to store the datetime as a long rather than datetime and convert in code behind for far away dates or higher precision?

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameterized query as Adrian suggested.

Another possibility is to use an ISO 8601 string representation like described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) which is independent of locale settings.

That would look like:

```
20110921 15:20:00
```

Comment: Actually with date only the safest format is YYYYMMDD. If time is included, the only truly safe format is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS[...]

Comment: @Aaron: MSDN says that is the *unseparated* ISO8601. Yours is the separated ISO8601.

Comment: For input literals this seems pretty clear to me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28SQL.90%29.aspx I don't see YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS mentioned there at all. I also don't see your format listed under ISO 8601 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx

Comment: @Aaron: I have read it on this msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx
In your second link its mentioned in the rows 1 (just date) and 11 (date with time)

Comment: I was just correcting that your format is not ISO 8601. Your format is, in fact, safe, but technically it is *NOT* ISO 8601 as you describe (ISO 8601 and Unseparated in that document are *separate* entries). ISO 8601 = `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`, unseprated = `YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss` and ANSI = `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` - ANSI is not safe from language differences but, I'll concede, the other two are. The format I suggested is not "the separated ISO 8601" it is just ISO 8601. "Separated" format in SQL Server is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and is definitely unsafe, but not listed on the page you reference.

Comment: @Aaron: Ok, you are right - i have combined the two table fragments into one :)

Comment: excellent discussion of language neutral date formats :   http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp .

Answer (score 0):

Either you use parametrized command/stored procedures where you create a parameter of type DateTime in the stored and assign it from .net code when you call the stored (so .NET and SQL will know they are working with a datetime and will never confuse/swap day and month), or you include a specific command on top of your insert commands and then format all dataetime strings with this pattern, for example:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
```

[SET DATEFORMAT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)